# run executable in current directory mac

Tags: macos

I write an GUI application in QT running in MAC SIERRA OS the work of this GUI is to execute some scripts and edit some that are located in the directory that the app exists!!

When i run the app from the QT IDE environment the app finds all the scripts and files which are included in the directory and it works as it has to work!

If now I try to run the app just double clicking it in the file explorer(finder in Mac) then the app can't find any script and file that need to find!!

The reason is that when I double click in the app the app is executed always in the "/" directory or in "Users/username" directory and IT IS NOT executed in the directory that it exists!!

Is there some way to change that behavior in this OS???

P.S:the same code works excellent in UBUNTU OS

Comment: Could you please first read your question before posting it? In this state it is extremely hard to read (missing punctuation marks, missing paragraphs), so I'm not even interested in answering whatever you might ask in there.

Comment: @C-Otto is it better now?

Comment: No, did you even change anything?

Comment: @C-Otto what you can't understand???

Comment: It hurts my eyes to read this wall of text. There's no code, it ends with "???", I see "!!" - overall you seem to ramble more than ask a professional question.

Comment: @C-Otto programming is fun and also we aren't judged from our !! ??? or logos that many people would consider as stupid as a bitten apple logo in  Mac ,we are judged from our  results ,so in the case you can't understand probably you have no fkg idea of what I m speaking or your brain is too much constrained to let it free and think!!!!!!!!

Comment: Maybe, but maybe your question should also be readable and easy to consume if you want to achieve the goal of getting an answer.

Comment: Where is the directory that it should be executing from, and what is different from executing it in the IDE vs. Finder?

Comment: I'L'I the directory is in the home directory /Users/myusername/directory     it has full permissions to all the users(I set that on purpose for debugging),and in Qt  IDE RUN configuration I set the path that I want the  builded file to be executed and  it works perfectly, if then I try to execute this file from terminal or just clicking in the finder it nothing works cause it runs out of the directory that is located

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like you need to either put the executable with those files, symlink it, or have a secondary launcher/script that launches the one which seems to need to reside in the directory you mentioned. Maybe edit your question and show the code which you are using; generally .apps on Mac need to be in a "bundle" or have dynamic libraries with runpaths set so they can reference them properly.

Comment: the app executable is in the folder with all the files needed, the QT gui  code just run a script with one line like "gedit ./myfile.py" but as the OS brings the executable in the root directory "/" the script can't find the "./myfile.py" so I would need a special config for the launcher in this app to make it be executed in the folder that is located and not changing working directory, i don't know how to do that..

Comment: final solution for the moment I created a script that will run my app containing the code "cd /mydesired_working_directory && ./MYAPP.app/Contents/MacOS/MYAPP"  so the script enter in  the App bundle and execute the executable no more solutions for the moment but this works